# REST-api structure when creating associated records during update

Tags: database, rest, endpoint

In my database, I have two tables, User and Location. Each user should have a location. If I have a user and want to update it, I use PUT on "users/:id", and could add locationId if I want to. What if location does not already exist? I am aware that I could first create a location and then update with the new locationId, but I would like to be able to do it in one request.

I have implemented a way to do this, where I can send a location-object under key: "location" in the body when doing the request in "users/:id". This works, but I understand that this means I am creating in my database, when the requests in itself is a PUT-request. I this allowed in REST, or do I need to do two requests to follow the best practices of REST? The two requests seems pretty annoying for client if I have multiple associations to the user, and would be a lot of requests.

Comment: Opinion - create any missing location in the user/:id PUT if the user's business rules allow - can't find any reference to back this up

Comment: You mean that the client should be allowed to send a location with the userobject, and if it doesnt exist we create the location? That is what I am doing right now and it works fine. I also feel like it is straight-forward and understandable for a client, however I am not sure if it follows REST-principles

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean.

Comment: Right, I feel like that would be the way to go. The only downside is it requires lots of manual work in the backend to first create the data that does not already exist and then update the user, but I guess that is worth it if it makes it easier for the client. Do you know how this problem is often solved, because I feel like it is quite a common scenario when for example onboarding a user